# Does a proxy consume same bandwidth as origin?

Tags: iptables, proxy, nat

i want to setup a proxy server [using NAT rules](https://superuser.com/questions/995292/hide-server-location?answertab=votes#tab-top).

My question is: using the linked method, does the proxy consume same bandwidth as the origin server?

Or only the origin consumes bandwidth and the proxy just points to a location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pointing to a location" is never what a (web) proxy does. The traffic will be sent through your proxy. Effectively, unless it is a caching proxy, you will double the amount of traffic your proxy uses when compared to direct connections - it needs to fetch the data from the backend and then send it on to the client.

Comment: Is the PREROUTING method linked considered a proxy? i may have used the term wrong. Or not.

Comment: I would not name it a proxy per se, but that's just terminology. The issue of the double data consumption remains.

Comment: Thank you. It's what i wanted to know ultimately. To calculate the needed bandwidth of the server passing trough the traffic.